# My ending sucked. Are there different endings possible?

Tags: rochard

I completed [Rochard](http://www.rochardthegame.com/en/), the other day, and my ending was horrible.  It's not really relevant to the question, but I'll give a brief description anyway (spoilers):

> Maximilian gets sucked into a vortex.  Rochard and Skyler talk for a bit, and Skyler begins to say something about a mysterious excavation which took place on Earth a number of years ago, and involved both Maximilian and her uncle Floyd.  Suddenly, a new vortex appears and both Rochard and Skyler are sucked into it.  The camera pans down to Rochard's 'Helga' mining tool, dropped on the ground, which lays there with a red blinking light on it.  Fade to credits.

So, understandably, I was left with a few questions.  I'm wondering if it's possible to achieve different endings to the game, given that this ending was so terrible.  Is this the only ending possible?  Or are there multiple endings?

Comment: I had the same experience.  I think they were setting up for a sequel that has yet to be released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the various sources I've found, there is only one ending in Rochard. There has been a somewhat mixed reaction to it and quite a few people have commented they're also left with questions unanswered.

> Quoted from [Critical Hit](http://www.crit-hit.net/rochard/):
>
> ...it’s like the writers give up and decide to just quit mid-sentence. At first I wondered if maybe the abruptness of it was related to my play time, and I’d have to do a speed run to get the complete ending, but this appears to not be the case. There’s a difference between a satisfying cliffhanger ending and an ending that comes across as incomplete...

<sup>[Source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=2237568) | [Source](http://occasionallywearsahat.com/tag/rochard/) | [Source](http://www.crit-hit.net/rochard/)</sup>

Comment: This is very disappointing.

Comment: It's like they planned a sequel, but never got around to making it.